# Only call getrows event with a button in ag grid server side javascript

Tags: javascript, button, server-side

I made an extrnal button outside the gird , so I can put all fillters then apply it with this button but the problem every time I filter somthing it calls getRows for server-side data

I need a way to call getRows only when I press a button

I trid this : if button not pressed ==>

```
params.success({
  rowData: [],
  rowCount: 0,
});
```